# Approaches to building tests to check if JSON files match TypeScript interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, testing

I have a bunch of API endpoints that are currently being tested in DRF. If the tests pass and they return a JSON response, I decided to save these responses to a folder. This would work as an "auto-updated" mock for my frontend to rely on.

In the frontend side, I would like to access these JSON files created by my backend and check if the TypeScript interfaces I provided for those responses match these saved responses.

As it seems to be a very common problem (mismatching backend and frontend requests/responses payloads), I wondered if there were any good libraries that implement this out-of-the-box. But it turns out it's not so straighforward. Usually these tests fall directly to E2E tests and I would like a more concise approach for now.

Does someone ahve a suggestion on what would be the best alternative to implement those simple tests with a tool that I could and likely would use later for more advanced tests as well?